# UICollectionView with UIView as delegate and datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I must be a complete noob, but I can't figure this out and need some help.

I have a `UIView` with a `UICollectionView` in it. When I add the collection view, I don't get a `UICollectionViewCell` in my nib for some reason I only get this when I add the collection view in a `UIViewController`. Part of my question is - is it possible to have a `UICollectionViewCell` in my nib file here?

I assumed the answer was no so I tried the following:

I created a separate nib file and class for my custom `UICollectionViewCell` and registered the custom cell to my collection view like this:

```
[self.itemsCollection registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
```

then in my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I do this:

```
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.itemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Some Image.png"];
cell.itemLabel.text = @"Some Title";
```

however, when my cell gets created the `itemImage` and the `itemLabel` are both `nil`.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've defined your `IBOutlet` references in the NIB, then you have to register the NIB, not the class. So, replace:

```
[self.itemsCollection registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
```

with

```
[self.itemsCollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
```

Your NIB can specify the base class of `CustomCollectionViewCell`.

Comment: That is golden my friend! Thank you so much! You're a champ.